# How to use JADE to create an agent to search webservices

Tags: web-services, agents-jade

I first heard of JADE many months back but never got the opportunity to try it. I did a simple google search to find out the way JADE is being used. I got [this](http://agents.develop123.com/index.php/getting-started-with-jade/87-integrating-jade-and-web-services-part2) and since then I really wanted to know much more about JADE.

At present, I have been given a project to create an agent that searches(categorically) for the webservices spread across the Internet and displays the response of each when identified. I wanted to know how can JADE be used to do such a task.

How should I go about it? Which tools and technologies should I be using ?

Can anyone share their thoughts on the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know how to implement an Java application that searches for online web services. Jade will be perfect for your project.

If you going to implement JADE it will consist of two distinct part. The actual java app that searches for the webservices and the JADE implementation. By using JADE you can create as many agents as you need over several different systems, thus spreading the workload and speeding up the execution.

The actual implementation of JADE on different systems is relatively easy because of the communication protocol implemented by JADE. To learn more about JADE I suggest to look into the following documents.

PDF: [JADE programming for beginners](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjade.tilab.com%2Fdoc%2Ftutorials%2FJADEProgramming-Tutorial-for-beginners.pdf&ei=x2TVTqf2G8SDOq7S5VE&usg=AFQjCNHGMoP3GHdY8-S6dbrhRVyvquWFQA&sig2=vxCP51Xc7s6HdIex6HABCA)

Distrubed JADE: [Creating distrubed JADE platforms](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/JadeContainerTutorial.html)